# DevOps pipelines - map environment variables from Azure KeyVault

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to get my .NET Core app to pick up secret values from Azure KeyVault in a DevOps pipeline. I want to map these onto environment variables which can be used to override the settings in an appsettings.json file.

I have mapped a variable group in the DevOps pipeline to KeyVault, and configured the corresponding variables for the pipeline. I have added some tasks to write the variables to output variables.

I'm trying to set a nested value in the JSON file, and there seems to be some confusion around which separator to use: "--", "__", or "."

In the yml I have this to load the variables from KV:

```
- task: AzureKeyVault@1
  displayName: 'Load Secrets'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: MySub
    KeyVaultName: 'A-Vault'
```

And next I'm trying to map the vars to output vars like this:

```
- powershell: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ConnectionStrings.DbConnectionString;isOutput=true]$(ConnectionStrings--DbConnectionString)"
  displayName: 'Set DbConnectionString'
```

The environment variable uses the "--" format used by Azure KeyVault and I'm trying to map it onto a variable using the "." format used in .NET Core configuration extensions. I have also tried using "__" in the output variable name, but same result.

I have added the AddEnvironmentVariables() config extension method in my startup, and the JSON settings file looks like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DbConnectionString": "env:ConnectionStrings__DbConnectionString"
  }
}
```

The error when I run my test indicates that it's using the default value from the JSON above, not the value from the environment variable. Any ideas what I might have missed, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you share the json?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk - sure, I have edited the question to include the relevant JSON

Comment: Can you add a task before the json just to print the variable value (ConnectionStrings__Db....)?